# How to split different values in powershell by a line

Tags: azure, command, devops, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine

With this script i am able to fetch all the Tags that a VM has but i want that in output the each key and its value should be separated by a line in the way that each key and its value appears on different lines like this
[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFi5n.jpg)

```
 # Sign into Azure Portal
    connect-azaccount

    # Fetch the Virtual Machines from the subscription
    $azureVMDetails = get-azvm

    # Fetch the NIC details from the subscription
    $azureNICDetails = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}

    #Fetching Virtual Machine Details
    $virtual_machine_object = $null
    $virtual_machine_object = @()

    #Iterating over the NIC Interfaces under the subscription
    foreach($azureNICDetail in $azureNICDetails){ 

        #Fetching the VM Name
        $azureVMDetail = $azureVMDetails | ? -Property Id -eq $azureNICDetail.VirtualMachine.id 
        #Fetching the VM Tags 
         foreach($azureDetail in $azureVMDetails) {
        $vm_tags = $azureVMDetail| Select-Object -Property (
        @{name='Tags'; expression = {($_.tags.GetEnumerator().ForEach({ '{0} : {1}' -f $_.key, $_.value }) -join ';')}}
    )

    }
        #VM Details export
        $virtual_machine_object_temp = new-object PSObject 
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "name" -Value $azureVMDetail.Name
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "comments" -Value ($vm_tags.Tags -join ';')
        $virtual_machine_object += $virtual_machine_object_temp
   
  }

    #Report format and path  
    $virtual_machine_object | Export-Csv "C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\Inventory\Final Scripts\VM_details_$(get-date -f dd.MM.yyyy).csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74059826/edit) the question and add examples of the output you're currently getting, and the output you want. Your textual description isn't really clear.

Comment: Okay let me rephrase it. My VM has more then one Tags and the output im getiing is like this "Test : Server; Dev : Server" in one line. These are two values for two keys and are separated by a ";"
I want that each Tag value and its key should appear on separate lines like this
Test : Server 
(on second line) Dev : Server

Comment: For reference i have added an image in description

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully by using the below PowerShell script:***

```
$vmdeatil = Get-AzVm -Name testvm | Select -ExpandProperty Tags
$value = $vmdeatil

foreach($i in 0..($value.Count -1))
{
$ErrorActionPreference = ‘SilentlyContinue’
    [array]$report += [pscustomobject]  @{
            key = $key[$i]
        name = $value[$i]
            }
}

$report | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\ruk1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Response:**

[image]

**The output is successfully exported in the `csv` file like below:**

[image]